# Incorporate luck in statistical modelling

Tags: neural-network, r, deep-learning, regression, prediction

I was wondering if it is possible (and if yes, how is it done) to incorporate a luck component in statistical models.

So let’s assume I’d perform a regression on the goal difference between two teams in order to model the outcome of a sports match. How could I also model a random luck component that would make the underdog draw or win in certain rare cases?

And what if I took it a step further and tried to model the match outcome using neural networks? Is is possible to include luck in this case?

Comment: Just use a probabilistic model. For example, if the probability of one team beating the other is $\sigma(w \cdot (team_1-team_2))$, where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is the logistic function, then there's always a probability that the weaker team will team. If you wanted to use a neural network you'd use it to replace the logistic function. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a probabilistic model. For example, if the probability of one team beating the other is $σ(w⋅(team1−team2))$, where $σ(⋅)$ is the logistic function, then there's always a probability that the weaker team will win.

If you wanted to use a neural network you'd use it to replace the logistic function.

<sub><sub>Answer copied from comments.</sub></sub>